# Android AIDL client

Tags: android

I've been reading about IPC using AIDL in Android. My question is simply when my application "A" create and expose a service with AIDL. How will my application "B" know the type of the exposed service (the interface defined in the AIDL), will the client application need to get a copy of the ".AIDL" file created in application "A"?

So, if I want to provide a service in my application, clients would require to know the intent they can bind the service to and get a copy of the AIDL file?

Also does Android provide any AIDL services with the default application package??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will the client application need to get a copy of the ".AIDL" file created in application "A"?

Yes.

> So, if I want to provide a service in my application, clients would require to know the intent they can bind the service to and get a copy of the AIDL file?

Yes.

> Also does Android provide any AIDL services with the default application package??

I have no idea what "the default application package" is, sorry.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. Sorry the default application package may be a confusing. I just mean does any of the standard android applications provide any AIDL services (those that comes pre packaged with the android system). Hmm actually maybe this is more a question to the device manifacture for example HTC?.

Comment: @madsleejensen: "I just mean does any of the standard android applications provide any AIDL services" -- ah, OK. The answer is "sort of". Most, if not all, of the system services (`getSystemService()`) like `LocationManager` are implemented under the covers using AIDL to communicate from your process to an OS process. However, the classes *you* interact with, like `LocationManager`, are not AIDL client proxies, but are wrappers around AIDL client proxies.